# Oracle APEX | How to remove row from tabular form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex, tabular-form

Simply I use want to remove a row from tabular form

I used this code

```
$('#f02_0000').remove();
```

**But** it removes only one column from that row whether I am trying to remove the whole row.

**Help Please!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to remove the parent row which has an attr `id='f02_0000'` in that row:

```
$('#f02_0000').closest("tr").remove();
```

Usually we have a input element in that row with some class say `class="deleteRow"` and you can use the following to delete that particular row onClick of that button in browser.

```
$( "input.deleteRow" ).click(function(event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
```